# Tab - delimited .csv file into R

Tags: r, read.table

I have a .csv file tab delimited.  While running the code

```
data <- read.table("xxx.csv",sep = "\t", dec=".", header = TRUE, 
                   encoding="UTF-8", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

R reads it as a single column without dividing (should make 42 columns).  Any ideas? [Link to file](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/5bf68f02225d529f102d83f5810bb3c320170911131610/c88ccd).

Comment: Thanks. Just ran it with sep=" ", but still sees it as 1 column.

Answer (score 6):

The problem arises because each line is between quotation marks (the whole line).

There are two possible ways to read the file.

- Keep all quotation marks.

  Use the parameter `quote = ""` to disable quoting.

  ```
  read.table("xxx.csv", sep = "\t", dec = ".", header = TRUE,
             encoding = "UTF-8", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, quote = "")
  ```
- Remove the quotation marks before reading the file.

  ```
  tmp <- gsub('^\"|\"$', '', readLines("xxx.csv"))
  read.table(text = tmp, sep = "\t", dec = ".", header = TRUE,
             encoding = "UTF-8", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  ```

Comment: Thanks. I ran it the first way you offered & it worked, though R saw the metrics in the file as text. I solved it on my end a bit differently. It seems that when i download the report in .csv form & open it in excell, R has this issue, but when I just download it & run the R code without opening the file, R works just fine (42 columns & metrics recognised as metrics)